# Why is MapPageRoute corrupting Html.Beginform action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  My html extension method is declared like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SomeMethod", "MotorcycleForSale", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "frmBrokers" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" id="BrokerId" name="BrokerId" />
}
```

It called the route expected

But then I added the

```
routes.MapPageRoute
            routes.MapPageRoute("HomeDef", "Home/Default", "~/WebForms/Default.aspx");
```

When I start the web app, it overwrites the form action as follows

```
<form id="frmBrokers" action="/Home/Default?action=SomeMethod&amp;controller=MotorcycleForSale" method="get">    <input name="BrokerId" id="BrokerId" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI:  Best I can figure out its a bug in MVC.  I quit using the html extension methods, switched to plain old html and everything worked fine.